# Angular short condition statement

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make some statement based on value first time in Angular, but i dont like the way i have two of elements that checks, this is what I have

```
<h4 class="modal-title" ng-show="::model.trainingModel.name !== undefined">{{'EDIT_TRAINING' | translate}}</h4>
<h4 class="modal-title" ng-show="::model.trainingModel.name === undefined">{{'NEW_TRAINING' | translate}}</h4>
```

Is it possible that someone help me to make it shorter?

Comment: you can't use one time binding `::` and a ternary `? :` operator in the same statement, so no, there is no way to have this be a single line, unless you set it in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

```
<h4 class="modal-title">{{( model.trainingModel.name ? 'EDIT_TRAINING' : 'NEW_TRAINING') | translate}}</h4>
```

Comment: But look this :: only first time

Comment: so you can use `::model.trainingModel.name`. I change the code above

Comment: Syntax Error: Token ':' not a primary expression

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten the code as:

```
<h4 class="modal-title" ng-show="model.trainingModel.name">{{'EDIT_TRAINING' | translate}}</h4>
<h4 class="modal-title" ng-show="!model.trainingModel.name">{{'NEW_TRAINING' | translate}}</h4>
```

OR Use:

```
<h4 class="modal-title">{{ model.trainingModel.name ? 'EDIT_TRAINING' : 'NEW_TRAINING'|translate}}</h4>
```

Comment: Still not more different than my question :(

Comment: But there is one-time binding syntax ::

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
<h4 class="modal-title" data-ng-init=" value = ( ::model.trainingModel.name !== undefined ) ? 'EDIT_TRAINING' : 'NEW_TRAINING'">{{ value | translate}}</h4>
```

I know `ng-init` is not appropriate in such cases. It should be use in for loop to init the values. But in your case it may work :)

Answer (score 0):

in your js/ts file create the template variable training and set it to:

```
this.training = model.trainingModel.name ? 'EDIT_TRAINING' : 'NEW_TRAINING'
```

then in your template include the new template variable